# Matching a set of detail types against multiple rows repeatedly

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a set of details for roster information.

I have a table of roster details. There is a ID# for each person, and about 50 rows of details for that ID#. The `PK` is ID#, detail type and date.

I'm trying to join the result of a sub-query against each row in the roster detail table, to find what people are missing what detail types.

I can achieve the results I want with an individual person:

```
select *
from (

    -- a big sub-query yielding 39 lines of the detail types I want

) list_of_details
left join textDetail td
    on td.detailType = list_of_details.detailType
    and td.sid_member = 2071
order by dt.sid_detailType
```

Yields:

```
detailType     ID          detailType     date_start              value_detail
-------------- ----------- -------------- ---------------------------------
1              2071        1              2017-03-14 00:00:00.000 test
1              2071        1              2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
2              2071        2              2017-03-14 00:00:00.000 test
2              2071        2              2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
3              NULL        NULL           NULL                    NULL
4              2071        4              2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
16             NULL        NULL           NULL                    NULL
17             2071        17             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
18             2071        18             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
19             2071        19             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
20             2071        20             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
21             2071        21             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
22             2071        22             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
23             2071        23             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
24             2071        24             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
25             2071        25             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
27             2071        27             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
28             2071        28             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
33             NULL        NULL           NULL                    NULL
34             NULL        NULL           NULL                    NULL
35             2071        35             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
36             2071        36             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
37             2071        37             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
38             2071        38             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
39             2071        39             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
40             2071        40             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
41             2071        41             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
42             2071        42             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
46             2071        46             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
47             2071        47             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
48             2071        48             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
51             2071        51             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
52             2071        52             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
53             2071        53             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
54             2071        54             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
55             2071        55             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
56             2071        56             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
57             2071        57             2017-03-14 16:58:50.037 NULL
58             NULL        NULL           NULL                    NULL
```

I'm not worried about the `NULL` in the `value_detail` column, this is a test user.

I need to repeat this query against several hundred users, and find which entries they are missing. Eg the above person is missing `detailType` 3, 16, 33, 34, 58

--EDIT--

Removing `and td.sid_member = 2071` yields only the matching rows. In this case, the results for `sid_member 2071` exclude rows where `detailType` does not occur, which is what I want.

Adding `where td.sid_member is null` returns no results

Comment: I made an update to my answer below.  You need a master list of ID and Detail Type.  You can then left join to that list to find your missing detail types per each unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

Remove or replace this line in your existing query:

```
 and td.sid_member = 2071
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there...  You just need to check for NULL in the textDetail side of things:

```
left join textDetail td
    on td.detailType = list_of_details.detailType
WHERE td.sid_member IS NULL
order by dt.sid_detailType
```

This basically gives you all your non-matches.

*** EDIT ***

Ok... since you didn't give us your table structure, I thought about this some more...

If you want your ID along with the missing detail types, you'll need to create a master list of ID's with all possible detail types using a cross join.  Then you can left join to that master list and grab your missing detail types per unique ID.

```
SELECT xid.ID, xid.detailType
FROM
   (SELECT i.ID, d.detailType
   FROM
   (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM textDetail) as i
   cross join (SELECT DISTINCT detailType FROM list_of_details) as d
   ) as xid
left outer join textDetail td
    on xid.ID = td.ID
    AND xid.detailType = td.detailType
WHERE td.detailType IS NULL
ORDER BY xid.ID, xid.detailType
```

This will now give you your non-matches per ID